# How to Update the column in whole Database?

Tags: oracle10g

Here is my situation, I have Table called **EMPDETAILS(empcode, empname)** with 10 records and some other tables that have **empcode** also.

```
**Example**
EMPCODE  EMPNAME
EMP001    A
EMP002    B
EMP003    C
```

Now I want to update the column **EMPCODE** EMP001 with 001 in whole Database

```
**OUTPUT**
EMPCODE EMPNAME
001       A
```

**NOTE: 1.** I Didn't set the primary key for the Parent Table.

Can any one please help?

Comment: Are you trying to change the data type from `varchar2` to `number`, or just replace one string value with another? I'm not quite sure what the issue is - what's the problem with updating all the tables independently, but in one transaction, if there is no constraint getting in the way?

Comment: one string value with another

Comment: no need to change the datatypes. my Client needs to replace the EMPCODE Value "D109" with some other Values like "201913" in all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to generate update statements

```
SELECT
       'UPDATE '
      || OWNER
      || '.'
      || TABLE_NAME
      || ' SET EMPCODE = SUBSTR ( EMPCODE, 1, 3); '
FROM
      SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE
      OWNER = '{owner}'
      AND COLUMN_NAME = 'EMPCODE';
```